# What is difference between these 3 statements RequireJS

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs

```
   //#1  return object with property assigned to function abc
define(function()){

    function abc(){}

    return {
      objMethod:abc
    }
})
    // #2  return directly function by objects property objMethod
 define(function()){

    return {
      objMethod: function abc(){};
    }

 })

    // #3  return function directly
 define(function()){

    return function abc(){};

  })
```

I feel all of the above function doing same thing except that last statement returning function others returning object ? do my understanding is correct , is it something related to public and private pattern.